# How to switch view controllers in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I can no longer simply right click and drag from a button to a view controller to create a view switch via the Modal function in Xcode 5?

I've searched everywhere, but seeing as Xcode 5 is fairly new, I can't find anything on it.
I'll continue to search the Apple Documentation just in case no one can provide an answer here, but does anyone know what's wrong?

Is this feature excluded from Xcode 5 and I am forced to code it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are talking about is called Storyboard Segue and it's definitely available in Xcode 5.

Be sure you are dragging from the `UIButton` and not from it's superview.

Restarting Xcode may also help.

Comment: I did a little research of my own, and you're absolutely right. My problem is that my project was created without Storyboard Segue since my Parse backend was auto generated through Parse. So I have to create a new project and design my app, then import my backend. Thank you for the help!